# PHP week date conversion

Tags: php, date

My date formatted like this `"2000-5-1"`. First digit represents 4 digit year. The second is number of week in year, and the last one represents number of day in week.

No matter what I do, function always returns false, my code is following:

```
date_create_from_format("Y-W-N", "2000-5-1")
```

([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

**Please avoid solutions that are using magic words like "+1 day" etc.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a DateTime object from a compound format with year/week/day is described in the [compound formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) section of the [supported date and time formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) section of the PHP Docs:

```
$x = new DateTime("2000-W05-1");
var_dump($x);
```

Note that the week number requires a leading zero

Result is a DateTime object for `2000-01-31`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documantation of [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (which is what you are using with an alias) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), there is not a 100% overlap of the formats, so you have a problem.

This is what I found that you could use as an alternative: [DateTime::setISODate](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php)

```
$date = explode('-','2000-5-1');
$newDate = new DateTime();
$newDate->setISODate($date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
```

setISODate will take the year, week and day as explained in the documentation to create a DateTime object.

Comment: Mark's answer also seems to be correct and as you can see in both cases you will need to manipulate your date string to get it to a format that you can use to construct the date, it's just up to your preference.